# How to generate an html with an array of values?

Tags: html, phpstorm, emmet

I'd like to know is there a way to generate html using array of values.

For instance, let’s say we have a simple Emmet abbreviation like this one:

```
ul>li*3>{Item$}
```

which produces snippet:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Wouldn’t it nice to specify an array of exact values of Item*?

It would be a very powerful technique when you need to generate a table or a form with lots of rows or input fields and when you know exact data to print out.

As I see, there is no such an opportunity in Emmet or PhpStorm live temples, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s Wrap with Abbreviation action for such cases: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/